# How to highlight specific date from mysql on monthcalendar using C#, Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, winforms

I'm a geologist and trying to make a time sheet application for my company with a poor C# knowledge and learning while programming.

I got a monthcalendar in my form and employee is choosing the dates he/she worked and saving to the datagridview *(to the dateStart and dateEnd columns on mysql, so we got an date interval here)*.

I would like to highlight *(or make bold, some specific look that employee can see which days he/she worked)* date interval that are saved to the mysql database. So, all occupied dates that are inserted to the db in the past, should be marked somehow.

Do you help me please?
Great thanks.

Comment: See the [MonthCalendar.AnnuallyBoldedDates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.annuallyboldeddates) and [MonthCalendar.MonthlyBoldedDates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.monthlyboldeddates). These are just arrays of DateTime objects you can easily fill with the results of a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the monthCalendar.AddBoldedDate() method to bold the date data in monthCalendar. Here is a simple example for your reference.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Enabled = false;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    String connetStr = "connection string";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connetStr);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string sql = "select * from  workday ";
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "workday");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        DateTime dateStart = (DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2];
        DateTime dateEnd = (DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3];
        DateTime[] dateRange = GetAllDays(dateStart, dateEnd);
        foreach (DateTime item in dateRange)
        {
            monthCalendar1.AddBoldedDate(item);
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

}

public DateTime[] GetAllDays(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2)
{
    List<DateTime> listDays = new List<DateTime>();
    DateTime dtDay = new DateTime();
    for (dtDay = dt1; dtDay.CompareTo(dt2) <= 0; dtDay = dtDay.AddDays(1))
    {
        listDays.Add(dtDay);
    }
    return listDays.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: @Yagiz If this answered your question, please [Upvote/Accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).